# How to get google charts X-Axis points starting at the left most point

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization, padding

I'm using the Google API for charts in my application. For that I'm using multiple charts in the same page. My problem is giving padding to the charts, if I give more points the chart area occupy more space in that div and if i give only a few points the chart area occupy less space and in center aligned. 
the first chart is aligned properly from left to right and the second chart with two points is aligned in center.
[image]

[image]

How do I make all the charts with the same alignment from left most to the right most point as like in the first chart?

Here is my code.

```
<script>                                                     

             var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['year', 'Cats'],                       
                    ['2009',   20],
                    ['2010',   23],
                    ['2011',   34],
                    ['2012',   43]
            ]);  
            var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['year', 'Cats'],                       
                    ['2007',   20],
                    ['2008',   23]

            ]);                 
        var options = {
            pointSize: 5,
            width: 211,
            height: 90,
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            chartArea: {
            left: 10,
            top: 10,
            width: 195,
            height: 56
        },
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            hAxis: {
            baselineColor: '#fff',
            gridlineColor: '#fff',
            textStyle: {italic: false, color: '#ccc', fontSize: 10}
        },
        vAxis: {
            baselineColor: '#fff',
            gridlineColor: '#fff',
            textPosition: 'none'
        },
        tooltip: {
            textStyle: {fontSize: 10}
        },
        series:{
            0:{
                color:'#0066CC'
            }
        }
    };
    var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
    var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart2'));
    chart1.draw(data1, options);
    chart2.draw(data2, options);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post two examples of the contents of `threeDatas` or `twoDatas`, one that generates your first chart and one that generates your second chart?

Comment: Here are some relevant options. You can specify the chartArea width, which is the area inside the axes, and the overall width of the chart with the top-level width option.  Also specify the chartArea left to say where the chart area starts relative to the overall area.

Comment: both of the threeData and fourData pointing the same options but the difference is the number of points to mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following fiddle for how I got the start and end points of both charts to be vertically aligned:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/E2yq6/

To achieve this I inserted null data points into "data2" to ensure that both charts would have the same amount of points:

```
var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['year', 'Cats'],                       
    ['2007',   20],
    [null, null],
    [null, null],
    ['2008',   23]
]);
```

I then used the "[interpolateNulls : true](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)" setting in the second chart's options object to automatically calculate the positions of the null data points.

As both charts now have the same amount of data points the end result is this:

[image]

Having to insert the null data points is far from ideal, but this solution shows that an answer to your question is possible.

Comment: if i use var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['year', 'Cats'],                       
        ['2009',   20],
        ['2010',   23],
        [null,null],
        ['2011',   34]
    ]); like this the alignment is varies... Please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/Hariprasath_V/PE8Ts/

Comment: My fiddle which you have updated still looks correct I.e. First and last points are aligned. You need to make your question clearer.

Comment: I still dont understand. In your fiddle you've removed a point from the first chart, show of course its going to look different. As I said before, the start and end points are still aligned, which is what you asked for in your question.

Comment: no there is some different in the length, will you please verify your's and my fiddle with alt-tab and see the difference between 2010 and 2011