# Is it possible to get the X-axis left aligned when using Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to get the X-axis left aligned when using Google Charts?

The chart will look better as there are more data points available (weekly updates), but it looks like crap when it's centered like it is by default.

I've been searching around without results.

[image]

Edit:

I guess this question is basically the same: [How to get google charts X-Axis points starting at the left most point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533529/how-to-get-google-charts-x-axis-points-starting-at-the-left-most-point?rq=1), but the accepted solution isn't worth it in my case. Anyone who knows of a better solution?

Comment: When using a discrete (string type) axis, you cannot force a particular axis alignment.  The only way is to add in dummy data rows like the other example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not possible without faking data points.